# Is there a way to print a dictionary in a reverse order?

Tags: python, dictionary, reverse, ordereddict

I have this ordered dict `od`:

```
OrderedDict([('and', 1), ('that', 1), ('this', 1), ('of', 1), ('truly', 1), ('something', 1), ('nothing', 1), ('important', 2), ('is', 3)])
```

I am trying to print the key value pairs of this dictionary in the reverse order. I tried this:

```
for k,v in od.items()[-1:]:
    print k,v
```

It prints:

```
is 3
```

But it prints only the last key value pair i.e. `('is',3)`. I want all the key value pairs in the reverse order like:

```
is 3
important 2
nothing 1
something 1
truly 1
of 1
this 1
that 1
and 1
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

Use `reversed`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('and', 1), ('that', 1), ('this', 1), ('of', 1), ('truly', 1), ('something', 1), ('nothing', 1), ('important', 2), ('is', 3)])

for k, v in reversed(d.items()):   #or for k, v in d.items()[::-1]
    print(k, v)
```

**Output:**

```
is 3
important 2
nothing 1
something 1
truly 1
of 1
this 1
that 1
and 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`reversed` is the way to go, but if you want to stay with slicing:

```
for k, v in od.items()[::-1]:
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have the error in list slicing.

`for k,v in od.items()[-1:]`
iterates from the last element to the end (prints only the last element)

[Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation/509295#509295)

In case you want just change your code

```
for k,v in od.items()[::-1]: # iterate over reverse list using slicing
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
od = OrderedDict([('and', 1), ('that', 1), ('this', 1), ('of', 1), ('truly', 1), ('something', 1), ('nothing', 1), ('important', 2), ('is', 3)])
od_list=[i for i in od.items()]

#Reverse the list
od_list.reverse()

#Create the reversed ordered List.
od_reversed=OrderedDict(od_list)
print(od_reversed)
    OrderedDict([('is', 3),
             ('important', 2),
             ('nothing', 1),
             ('something', 1),
             ('truly', 1),
             ('of', 1),
             ('this', 1),
             ('that', 1),
             ('and', 1)])
```